# basic question ruby store value from table to array

Tags: ruby

I read that initialitation of array in ruby is like
myarray = [apple.txt, house.txt]

How can I store the value of a table in an array

```
if !haus.blank?
            #from below, I will get a list of haus.name that I need to store in an array 
            haus.each do |f|
                   hausname = haus.name
          end
end
```

i need to store each of the haus.name that I get from iterating in haus table to

myarray=[listofhaus.name]

How can I do this in ruby?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the array of names using the map

```
 myarray = haus.map {|f| f.name} or
 myarray = haus.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myarray = haus.collect(&:name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I take i you're on Rails. Since your each iteration doesn't really make sense, here's a generic example:

```
Haus.all.map {|h| h.name }
```

This get's all objects of model Hause and maps the name attribute of each into an array.

Comment: He didn't mention Rails, but even if he did, that wouldn't be very efficient, especially if there are lots of fields in the Haus model.

Comment: He talks about tables, thus the assumption. You're right, it's not very efficient. And <code>map(&:name)</code> is nicer and does the same. I'm voting up yours.